# VBA: Hide Columns on Cell Change

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to vba and I want to hide a set of columns through the workbook when a cell change happens. I compiled a list of code from research in Google but it doesn't work. Please check my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Keycells As Range
    Set Keycells = Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("B4")

    If Not Application.Intersect(Keycells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call HideColumn
    End If

End Sub
Sub HideColumn()
    If Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value = 0 Then
        Worksheet("Sheet3").Columns("V:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Worksheet("Sheet4").Columns("V:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Worksheet("Sheet3").Columns("V:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Worksheet("Sheet4").Columns("V:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it works fine. I changed some stuff up so it looks a bit cleaner.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Keycells As Range
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    'sets a reference to Sheet2
    Set ws2 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    'I redefined Keycells to be a bit easier to read and use
    Set Keycells = ws2.Cells(4, 2)

    'The previous trigger you had wasn't entirely intuitive to me, so I remade it. 
    'The IsEmpty() function is a built-in function you can call to 
    'determine if a cell is empty.
    If Not IsEmpty(Application.Intersect(Keycells, Target)) Then
        Call HideColumn
    End If

End Sub

Sub HideColumn()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim ws4 As Worksheet

    'sets a reference to Sheet1
    Set ws1 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'sets a reference to Sheet3
    Set ws3 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    'sets a reference to Sheet4
    Set ws4 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")

    'I cleaned-up your previous statement to be a bit easier to read
    If ws1.Cells(4, 2).Value = 0 Then
        'hides columns V through Z on Sheet3
        ws3.Columns("V:Z").Hidden = True
        'hides columns V through Z on Sheet4
        ws4.Columns("V:Z").Hidden = True
    Else
        ws3.Columns("V:Z").Hidden = False
        ws4.Columns("V:Z").Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

To answer your question about where to put the Sub, you may put the HideColumn Sub in whatever Module or Sheet you wish, assuming you've created the Sub with the Public prefix like so:

```
Public Sub MySub()
    'do the thing
End Sub
```

However, if you have MySub() with the Private prefix in Module1, then you cannot call it from Module2. You can use the Private prefix like so:

```
Private Sub MySub()
    'i did my thing
End Sub
```

The Private Worksheet_Change() Sub, I think, needs to be in Sheet2. In the Project Explorer, right click Sheet2 -> View Code -> enter the Worksheet_Change sub there.

Comment: This is placed in a module right? Also there is nothing wrong with the code of my trigger? Did you use the same?

Comment: I changed my answer to make your code easier to read and test it.

Comment: If my answer helped the most, remember to make it the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'MsgBox ("inChange")
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then
        Call HideColumn(Target)
    End If
End Sub

Sub HideColumn(Target As Range)
    'MsgBox ("inHide")
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook
    If wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value = 0 Then
        wb.Sheets("Sheet3").Columns("V:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        wb.Sheets("Sheet4").Columns("V:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        wb.Sheets("Sheet3").Columns("V:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        wb.Sheets("Sheet4").Columns("V:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @mikkel-wilkinson-yang This goes in code-behind the sheet